From std::vector to pointer-to-array (most C++-style solution)
In the C++ application that I am writing, at some point, I have to interface with a C API and call a function whose signature is
int foo(const double(*bar)[3], const int N) 

My bar is a std::vector<double> whose size is a multiple of 3. This design is required by other parts of the application and cannot be changed. Therefore, to pass bar from my source code to foo, I arranged the following C-style solution:
auto bar = std::vector<double>(3 * N); // for some int N known only at runtime
// a lot of code that uses bar
// ...
// Call to C function "foo"
auto *bar_p = bar.data()
int result = foo((double(*)[3])(&bar_p), N)

which compiled but made clang-tidy to complain about using C-style arrays. I also tried with some static_cast solutions, but the compiler did not accept them. Furthermore, clang-tidy also complained when I tried to use reinterpret_cast.
Which is the supposed/canonical/best/"right" C++-way to pass bar to foo?
P.S.: C++17 or higher

What is this foo function supposed to do? Why does it need a pointer to an array? Perhaps it really expects an array of arrays? Where is the function coming from? If it's from inside your company then please talk to the team who wrote it. If it's a third part library function, then please contact them. And in either case you need to talk to your team and your leads.

the right way to do it is to build an array of pointers like the function expects and pass that array to the function.

@Someprogrammerdude It works on an array of 3-element arrays (3D points in space). I forgot to insert N in the signature, I am going to insert it.

So it really expects double [N][3]? Then the only way to do it properly is to create such an array. Which can be done using a std::vector<double[3]>. Or as suggested by @NathanOliver create an old C-style "dynamic" array and pass that.

@Someprogrammerdude std::vector<double[3]> still makes clang-tidy to complain about C-style arrays, such as any other solution based on C-style array.

@JtTest please provide MCVE proving something is wrong with std::vector<double[3]>. It works for me: https://godbolt.org/z/c1qz1b6WP - clang tidy finds nothing, sonar cube also finds nothing and all compilers are happy.

If you are required to use C-style arrays in your C++ code, I think the proper thing would be to turn off the clan-tidy warning for the same.

C++20 version with std::span<double[3]> alos looks fine: https://godbolt.org/z/9WWebGh7r

@MarekR Note that clang-tidy with no options does nothing at all. You have to pass list of check you want to enable, and indeed it does complain about C-style arrays: https://godbolt.org/z/fqM9saMdT (-checks=* is very spammy, but C-style array check is reported by both cppcoreguidelines-* and modernize-*, which I'd consider useful)

@Marek MCVE code. On my PC, running clang-tidy main.cpp -checks=*,-google-* on that code returns the warnings I was talking about (clang-tidy version: 14.0.0). As to the compiler, I did not state that it was unhappy.

@Eljay Even if I could, how could I make things to work when calling foo?

@NathanOliver, there is no array of pointers. This is a pointer to an array of double triplets, like e.g. coordinates in 3D.

@JtTest IMO best approach is use type alias and disable warning just for that line https://godbolt.org/z/xWET11TY5 Note alose that prefixing foowith extern "C" also changes behavior of clang-tidy.

@JtTest I think only copying it as in my answer will prevent the UB and will be clang-tidy friendly without changing bar definition

If your requirements is "no reinterpret_cast allowed and don't copy the input data" then the simplest way to do this is to create a wrapper c lib which defines a function int foo_wrapper(const double* bar, const int N), which you can very easily call from c++ having only a std::vector<double> without requiring a cast. Of course, in C you just use a "C style" cast to get your const double(*)[3]. (If this seems silly, perhaps reconsider your requirements.)

If it has no error, performance ok, and working. Evil code (not dirty) is ok for me.

Since you need to be able to provide a pointer to the first double[3] in a contiguous memory area, you will need to actually create double[3]s in that area. The simple solution is to use a std::vector<double[3]> or even a std::unique_ptr<double[3]> and suppress the clang-tidy warning. Provide a motivation, should you get negative code reviews:
// NOLINTNEXTLINE(modernize-avoid-c-arrays) C array used with C API
std::vector<double[3]> bar(N);
// ...
int result = foo(bar.data(), static_cast<int>(bar.size()));

or
// NOLINTNEXTLINE(modernize-avoid-c-arrays) C array used with C API
std::unique_ptr<double[3]> bar(new double[N][3]{});
int result = foo(bar.get(), N);


MSVC seems to not like std::vector<double[3]> Demo.

@Jarod42 Hmm... Well, I think it'll accept std::unique_ptr<double[3]>, so that's always an option. I added that to the answer.

This solution is clean and clear, but requires to define bar differently, which is a design constraint. What is surprising (at least for me) is that it seems there is no "clean" way to view a std::vector<double>(3*N) as a std::vector<double[3]>(N) without incurring in some violation or complaints.

@JtTest Yes, C++ is a bit restrictive when it comes to viewing objects through the eyes of another type. For non-char types, I think that's only defined for std::complex. On the upside, a std::vector<double[3]> does not require any cast and sending in bar.data() has defined behavior (unlike a reinterpret_cast would have if you cast std::vector<double>::data() to a pointer to a double[3]). It's also easier to access elements by index in the std::vector<double[3]>.

@JtTest Also, design constraints that requires you to rely on undefined behavior or doing unnecessary transformations when there are solutions with defined behavior that are costless should be challenged.

I am afraid there is no std portable solution to the problem. But it's at least possible to force compilation to fail if a supposed solution is not applicable. I am a proponent of always using std::array instead of raw C arrays. When interfaced with C API, we are usually certain that data types have standard layouts. So, we only need to assert that std::array can replace raw C arrays. So here's my first trail:
#include <span>
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

typedef double raw_double_3[3];
using double_3 = std::array<std::remove_extent_t<raw_double_3> ,std::extent_v<raw_double_3>>;

auto cpp_foo(std::span<const double_3> val){ 
    static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<double_3>);
    static_assert(sizeof(double_3)==sizeof(raw_double_3));

    auto const &ref = reinterpret_cast<const raw_double_3&>(front(val));
    return foo(&ref, size(val));
};

This wrapper can handle std::vector<double_3> as well as std::array<double_3, N> or raw array of double_3 elements. As long as the assertions succeed(very [[likely]]), the compiled wrapper is UB-free. In the unlikely event that the assertions fail, we can look for other workarounds. In either case we should investigate provable preconditions for UB-free and declare static_assert on them. Thus, the code either runs bug-free, or fails to compile.
Compiler/sanitizer warnings may still be present; because we are doing some unorthodox ad-hoc anyway. But it's readable and we have the safety proof (proper static_assert declarations), which also serve as minimal self documentation too.

he does not want reinterpret_cast. I deleted my answer with it

@0___________ I have no personal problem with reinterpret_cast, clang-tidy has.

@JtTest If you don't really care, and just want to avoid the warning, then just use placement new: double (*bar3)[3] = new (bar.data()) double[bar.size()][3];. (The size is irrelevant, put whatever number you'd like in there.)

I think it is still technically UB.

@0___________ UB has preconditions. Can you point out those preconditions? std::array is an aggregate, if it is also std layout too, then it's essentially a POD. std layout also implies that the first member and the object share base address. The only remaining thing to prove is that std::array has a raw array member. I take that one for granted, because how else? Would anyone spend an intrinsic extension on what's achieved through library? Give an option that doesn't involve casting, while improving the interface.

@Red.Wave IMO without copying there is no way of avoiding UB.

@0___________ I asked for a precondition to prove a case of UB. I don't see it. A platform dependent solution is the best I can see. There are other options too, but I need to validate the available std tools now.

To be portable and 100% UB free you need to create a new object and copy data to it
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef> // For std::size_t

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
T (*vector_to_array(const std::vector<T>& vec, std::size_t& out_rows))[N] 
{
    std::size_t total_elements = vec.size();
    std::size_t rows = (total_elements + N - 1) / N; 
    out_rows = rows;

    T (*array_ptr)[N] = new T[rows][N]; // Allocates 'rows' arrays of 'N' elements

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < total_elements; ++i) 
    {
        array_ptr[i / N][i % N] = vec[i];
    }

    for (std::size_t i = total_elements; i < rows * N; ++i)  
    {
        array_ptr[i / N][i % N] = T(); 
    }

    return array_ptr;
}

or using smart pointers
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
std::shared_ptr<T[][N]> vector_to_array(const std::vector<T>& vec, std::size_t& out_rows)
{
    std::size_t total_elements = vec.size();
    std::size_t rows = (total_elements + N - 1) / N;
    out_rows = rows;
    T (*array_ptr)[N] = new T[rows][N];
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < total_elements; ++i)
    {
        array_ptr[i / N][i % N] = vec[i];
    }
    for (std::size_t i = total_elements; i < rows * N; ++i)
    {
        array_ptr[i / N][i % N] = T();
    }
    auto deleter = [](T (*p)[N])
    {
        delete[] p;
    };
    return std::shared_ptr<T[][N]>(array_ptr, deleter);
}

The whole example:
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
std::shared_ptr<T[][N]> vector_to_array(const std::vector<T>& vec, std::size_t& out_rows)
{
    std::size_t total_elements = vec.size();
    std::size_t rows = (total_elements + N - 1) / N;
    out_rows = rows;
    T (*array_ptr)[N] = new T[rows][N];
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < total_elements; ++i)
    {
        array_ptr[i / N][i % N] = vec[i];
    }
    for (std::size_t i = total_elements; i < rows * N; ++i)
    {
        array_ptr[i / N][i % N] = T();
    }
    auto deleter = [](T (*p)[N])
    {
        delete[] p;
    };
    return std::shared_ptr<T[][N]>(array_ptr, deleter);
}

int foo(const double (*bar)[3], const int N) 
{
    // Example implementation to demonstrate access
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) 
    {
        std::cout << bar[i][0] << " " << bar[i][1] << " " << bar[i][2] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0; 
}

void callFoo(int n) 
{
    auto bar = std::vector<double>(3 * n);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3 * n; ++i) 
    {
        bar[i] = static_cast<double>(i);
    }

    std::size_t outr;
    auto bar_p = vector_to_array<double,3>(bar, outr);

    // Call foo
    int result = foo(bar_p.get(), n);
    std::cout << "result = " << result << " out_rows = " << outr << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;  
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); 

    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distrib(5, 10);
    callFoo(distrib(gen));
}

https://godbolt.org/z/MbGGe954j
added MSVC executor: https://godbolt.org/z/9jfoqMzK3
